# Check request source IP against dynamic data using Spring Securiy WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-security, ip-restrictions

Assuming I have the following class code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasIpAddress("runtime other device ip");
    }
}
```

at runtime, when a request is entering the system, I want to validate it came from "runtime other device ip", which can be different at time the request retrieved.

Please assume I have a utility that can retrieve this "runtime other device ip" `Utility.getOtherDeviceIP();`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `.access()` with a custom bean, that has your Utility class @Autowired and takes the current HttpServlet request as parameter, which Spring will inject for you automatically (next to the current authentication object).

Example:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").access("@yourCustomIpCheckerBean.check(authentication, request)");

}
```

Though, you could probably also directly write it as SpEL, if it is *just* your utility needed for the IP check. Something like (not tested):

```
.access("request.remoteAddr == @yourUtility.getOtherDeviceIP()")
```